# Snackbar's height customization

Tags: java, android, material-design, snackbar

When I loose connection within the Youtube Android app, there's a little `Snackbar` that appears on the bottom saying there's no connection.

That `Snackbar` is considerably smaller (in height) to a normal `Snackbar` and font size seems smaller also. Couldn't find documentation or either references on it. Should I create a custom `View` for that or is there any simple way to do so?

Also a related question: is it applicable within material design parameters to create that "mini-snackbar"? I see no reference to it in io.materialdesign website but nethertheless Google uses it on the Youtube app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300937/how-to-fix-the-snackbar-height-and-position

Comment: Create your own custom `snackbar` its not that difficult

Comment: @AkshayKatariya but would it contradict the material design suggestion?

Comment: those are guidelines but there are many awesome designs which can be formed just by bending some rules/concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though, the `Snackbar` does not allow you to set a custom layout, you can get its `View`. Then, you can access (and alter) its `LayoutParams`, which you use to change the layout parameters of the `Snackbar` including its height.

Alternatively, you could create your custom `Snackbar` by extending `BaseTransientBottomBar` class. Also, you may consider looking into using one of the many external libraries featuring custom `Snackbar` implementations: Here's an example I've been using for a while already: [CSnackBar](https://github.com/ChathuraHettiarachchi/CSnackBar)